# MongoDB order by "number" ascending

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a registration form with mongoose and MongoDB. I have a unique key, UserId, and every time I create a new entry I would like to take the greatest UserId in the database and increase it by one.
I tried with `db.user.find({}).sort({userId: 1});` but it seems not to work.
Thanks

Masiar

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do sounds more like a Schema for Relational Databases with an Auto Increment. I would recommend another solution.

At first you already have a unique id. It get automatically created and are in "_id" field. For me it seems you want to have a UserID for building relation, but you already ca use the value in _id.

The other thing why you want incremented ids could be that you create a webapplication and propably want "nicer" urls? For example. /user/1 instead of /user/abc48df...?

If that is the case i would prefer to create a unique constraint on a username. And instead of an id you use you username in the url "/user/john".

With this your urls are much nicer. And for building relation you can use _id. And you don't run into problems with fethcing the highest number first.

To create a unique index:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({username: 1}, {unique: true})
```

Comment: Also, you can override the `_id` field. That field is automatically unique. If your users have unique names, you can save them with `_id:'gates'` and save yourself an index as well.

Comment: I would not recommend putting the name in "_id". In your application you work with the "_id" field instead of a useful named "username". That could be harder to read/understand by other programmers. Second, if you build a relation then you can't change the username. If you change the username, then you destroy all relations. Or you need to change all relations too.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this to get the user with the current highest `UserId`:

```
db.user.insert( { UserId: 1 } )
db.user.insert( { UserId: 2 } )
db.user.insert( { UserId: 3 } )

db.user.find().sort( { UserId: -1 } ).limit(1)
```

It's worth noting that there isn't a way in MongoDB to fetch this value and insert a new user in a single atomic transaction, it only supports atomic operations on single documents. You'd need to take care that another operation didn't insert another user at the same time, you could end up with two users with the same UserId.

To iterate over the cursor and get put the returned doc in an array:

```
var myArray = [];
User.find().sort('UserId','descending').limit(1).each(function(err, doc) {
    myArray.push(doc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just a small question. The operation you told me does return an array, right? It would be var result = db.user.find().sort( { UserId: -1 } ).limit(1); right?

Comment: It'll return a cursor rather a single value, which you can then iterate over and load into an array.

Comment: any clue on how to iterate through it? I tried to console.log it but it prints something strange, like `{ model: [Function: model], op: 'find' }` and I don't know what really is.

Comment: Not a mongoose expert, but I've added I snippet that might help. Probably not the best way to do it!

Comment: Thanks for your snippet, but sadly it prints an empty array ([]). Thanks again! I'll figure it out myself! :)